# Wrong tooltip shown for data point

Tags: chart.js

I have two y-axes, the issue is in the second y-axis: the points appear in the right spot in the graph but the tooltip with the corresponding data only appears when I hover over the first two points in the x-axis. I have made `showLine` property as false since I want it to be a scatter chart. So I am not passing data for all points in the x-axis. This is the data:

```
[{x: 7, y: 4},
{x: 18, y: 1}]
```

[image]

```
const data = {
        labels: [] as number[],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Words Per Minute',
                data: [] as number[],
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: mainColor,
                borderColor: mainColor,
                borderWidth: 3,
                lineTension: 0.4,
                yAxisID: 'y',
            },
            {
                label: 'Incorrect Characters',
                data: [] as any[],
                fill: true,
                borderColor: function (context: any) {
                    const dataPoint = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    if (dataPoint && dataPoint.hasOwnProperty('y') && dataPoint.y === 0) {
                        return 'transparent';
                    } else {
                        return errorColor;
                    }
                },
                backgroundColor: function (context: any) {
                    const dataPoint = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    if (dataPoint && dataPoint.hasOwnProperty('y') && dataPoint.y === 0) {
                        return 'transparent';
                    } else {
                        return errorColor;
                    }
                },
                borderWidth: 3,
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointHoverRadius: 8,
                showLine: false,
                yAxisID: 'y1',
                pointStyle: 'cross'
            },
        ],
    };
```

y-axis code

```
y1: {
                position: 'right',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Incorrect Characters',
                    color: subColor,
                    font: {
                        size: 16,
                        family: 'lexend, sans-serif',
                    },
                },
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    precision: 0,
                    font: {
                        family: 'lexend, sans-serif',
                    },
                    color: subColor,
                    callback: function (value: any, index: number, values: string | any[]) {
                        if (incorrectChars.length !== 0) {
                            return value;
                        } else {
                            if (index === values.length - 1) return 1;
                            else if (index === 0) return 0;
                            else return '';
                        }
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    color: "transparent"
                },
                border: {
                    color: subColor
                }
            },
```

**Update**

Here is how I am getting incorrect chars dataset:

```
const calculateIncorrectChars = (
    incorrectCharsHistory: {
        word: string;
        idx: number;
        totalIncorrectCharacters: number;
        incorrectCharacters: number;
        extraCharacters: number;
    }[]
) => {
    const incorrectCharsDataset = incorrectCharsHistory
        .map((item, _) => {
            return { x: item.idx + 1, y: item.totalIncorrectCharacters };
        })
        .filter((x) => x.y !== 0);
    return incorrectCharsDataset;
};
```

If I use `filter()` to remove points where `y = 0` then this the output:

```
[{x: 7, y: 4},
{x: 18, y: 1}]
```

and the issue happens here, where the tooltip appears when I hover over point: `{x: 1}`

But If I don't use `filter()` then this is the output:

```
[{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 2, y: 0}, {x: 3, y: 0}, {x: 4, y: 0}, {x: 5, y: 0}, {x: 6, y: 0}, {x: 7, y: 4}]
```

and here the tooltip appears for the correct data point

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The image you posted shows the tooltip for the first point `{x: 7, y: 4}` and it seems OK to me.

Comment: The first point isn't `{x: 4, y: 7}`, it is the fourth point from the x-axis but the tooltip for this point only appears when I hover over `{x: 1}`

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wejuofks/) I made trying to understand what the problem is with your chart. As it is, it works as expected. If you think it helps to make us understand the issue, please modify it and post the version exhibiting the abnormal behavior.

Comment: It works in plain html and js, but in react-chartjs-2, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Then a codesanbox or stackblitz with a version of the react app that doesn't work would help to get an answer

Comment: Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-estrela-m6ph69?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The problem seems to be the interaction `mode: "index"`, it seems it actually means the index in the dataset so the first point of the second dataset is paired with the first point of the first dataset, at `x=1`. See if the interaction `mode: "x"` is convenient [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-waterfall-5i7gnl?file=/src/chart.js); an alternative we may try is to generate points in the second dataset with all the `x` values of the first dataset and `null` for `y` where there's no actual point.